# Where in the Bible does it mention that every person has a guardian angel?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, angels, guardian-angels

The Bible talks about various angels such as Saint Gabriel and Saint Michael.  Where in the Bible does it mention that every person has his/her own guardian angel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s2c1p5.htm) teaches that there is a guardian angel for each person.  It is well to recall that while the Catholic Church does not confine its teaching to *sola scriptura,* there is scriptural support for the teaching that angels are assigned as protectors.  Angels engage in a variety of tasks as described in scripture, to include protection of the faithful.  In English the term "guardian angel" is a way to describe an angel who protects someone.

> **The angels in the life of the Church**
>
> 334 In the meantime, the whole life of the Church benefits from the
>   mysterious and powerful help of angels.
>
> 335 In her liturgy, the Church joins with the angels to adore the
>   thrice-holy God. She invokes their assistance (in the funeral
>   liturgy's In Paradisum deducant te angeli. . .["May the angels lead
>   you into Paradise. . ."]). Moreover, in the "Cherubic Hymn" of the
>   Byzantine Liturgy, she celebrates the memory of certain angels more
>   particularly (St. Michael, St. Gabriel, St. Raphael, and the guardian
>   angels).
>
> 336 From its beginning until death, human life is surrounded by their
>   watchful care and intercession.  "Beside each believer stands an
>   angel as protector and shepherd leading him to life." (203) Already here
>   on earth the Christian life shares by faith in the blessed company of
>   angels and men united in God.

St Basil notes this in his description of the distinction between spiritual beings:

> (203) [St. Basil, Adv. Eunomium III, I: PG 29,656B.](http://books.google.com/books?id=KPbi_nBITycC&lpg=PA11&ots=EwVTjhI5su&dq=basil%20against%20eunomius&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=basil%20against%20eunomius&f=false)
>    All the angels,
>   having but one appelation, have likewise among themselves the same
>   nature, even though some of them are set over nations, *while others of
>   them are guardians to each one of the faithful*.

Scriptural verses that inform this teaching include:

Matthew 18:10

> 10 "See that you do not despise one of these little ones, for I say to
>   you that their angels in heaven always look upon the face of my
>   heavenly Father.

Hebrews 1:14

> "Are they [i.e. angels] not all ministering spirits sent out to serve
>   for the sake of those who are to inherit salvation?"

Luke 16:22

> 22 When the poor man died, he was carried away by angels to the bosom
>   of Abraham.

Psalm 34:7

> The angel of the Lord encamps around those who fear him, and he
>   delivers them

Psalm 91:10-13

> 10 no harm will overtake you, no disaster will come near your tent.
>   11 For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all
>   your ways;   12 they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will
>   not strike your foot against a stone.   13 You will tread on the lion
>   and the cobra; you will trample the great lion and the serpent.

Job 33:23-24

> 23 1 If then there be for him an angel, one out of a thousand, a
>   mediator, To show him what is right for him and bring the man back to
>   justice,
>
> 24 He will take pity on him and say, "Deliver him from going down to
>   the pit; I have found him a ransom."

Zech 1:11-14

> 11 And they answered the angel of the LORD who was standing among the
>   myrtle trees and said, "We have patrolled the earth; see, the whole
>   earth is tranquil and at rest!"    12  Then the angel of the Lord
>   spoke out and said, "O LORD of hosts, how long will you be without
>   mercy for Jerusalem and the cities of Judah that have felt your anger
>   these seventy years?"   13  To the angel who spoke with me, the LORD
>   replied with comforting words.   14 And the angel who spoke with me
>   said to me, Proclaim: Thus says the LORD of hosts: I am deeply moved
>   for the sake of Jerusalem and Zion,

Tobit 5:17

> Tobit said, “Blessing be upon you, brother.” Then he called his son
>   and said to him: “Son, prepare whatever you need for the journey, and
>   set out with your kinsman. May God in heaven protect you on the way
>   and bring you back to me safe and sound; may his angel accompany you
>   for your safety, son.”

---

Comment: While it seems the question is about biblical references to **guardian** angels, Basil's comments are not from scripture and at least some of your biblical references do not appear to mention guardian angels in particular. Could you please clarify whether you see any specific mentions of angels that are guardian angels?

Comment: @DickHarfield I think you missed my point.  Remember, the RCC does not limit itself to *sola scriptura* and the tag catholic was included.  Thus, there is some scripture and some other input.  The passage from Matthew seems rather obvious to me, but perhaps you choose not to read it that way.  The passage from Job is likewise an obvious reference to an angel who protects a given person.  From that, a rational description ... a guardian (protecting) angel. (Basil's term was the greek term for "one who stands beside" which means protector/guardian.  Also note the tag "Catholic" in the question.

Comment: I'd also add Hebrews 1:14: "Are they [i.e. angels] not all ministering spirits sent out to serve for the sake of those who are to inherit salvation?"

Comment: @Rev.AaronSimms Added that, and thank you.

Comment: +1 informative answer. I believe that the Orthodox church also believes in guardian angels, so the belief is shared by the two great monolithic churches of East and West.

Comment: Acts 12:15 is another relevant verse.

Answer (score 2):

The Bible does not use the term guardian Angel, the term Guardian was added by mankind.

That was added as a descriptor to separate the Angels described in the following Scripture from other Angels.

> Matthew 18:10 KJV  Take heed that ye despise not one of these little ones; for I say unto you, That in heaven their angels do always behold the face of my Father which is in heaven.

Nowhere else in Scripture, that I can find; does Jesus assign any particular function to any group of Angels. There are Angelic functions enumerated in the Revelation, but those are attributed to Jesus by John.

Hope this helps.

Comment: King James should have read Tobit!

Comment: @PeterTurner if Tobit were a part of the King James and not considered Apocryphal; by Southern Baptist of which I am one, Or  had the question asked for the Catholic opinion I would have quoted it. But, you might feel free to answer the question and indicate that in the Douay Rheims version in the book of Tobit it does specifically say 'guardian' and quote that verse.

Comment: @PeterTurner even with your answer I still hold that there is no use of the word *guardian* in reference to any Angel and stand by my assertion that guardian is a descriptor added by man.

Answer (score 2):

I just read this last night doing the readings for our families Jesse Tree.

Tobit takes it for granted that the traveler who is to accompany his son Tobias has an angel appointed to him by God

> Tobit said, “Blessing be upon you, brother.” Then he called his son and said to him: “Son, prepare whatever you need for the journey, and set out with your kinsman. May God in heaven protect you on the way and bring you back to me safe and sound; may his angel accompany you for your safety, son.”
>
> [TB 5:17 - NABRE](http://usccb.org/bible/tobit/5:17)

So, that's pretty cool!  Even though Tobit is actually talking about an St. Raphael the Archangel's angel.

The footnotes in the Catholic Study Bible, say this is a reference to his guardian angel.